# angular2: css target selector not working

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to follow this example(http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/) to create my own modal in an Angular2 project.

In my html template, I have

```
 <a href="#openModal" (click)="openDialog()" >Open Modal again</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>Modal Box</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason that I add `(click)="openDialog()"` to `<a>` is because `href="#openModal"` is not registered to the router. I have to prevent the default behavior in the method.

And, in the corresponding scss file, I have

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
```

In the component's ts file, I have the following method binding to the click event of my link.

```
openDialog(){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

The above code snippet is to popup a modal after user clicks the link; however, nothing happended after doing it. I think the css`.modalDialog:target` selector is actually not working for some reasons so that the opacity has not been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `preventDefault()` you stop that element from becoming the target of the `#hash`.

<del>You'll have to remove the `preventDefault()` call in order to set `#openModal` as the target of the hash of the URL on click, and use the `:target` selector.</del>

The OP has stated that this works:

```
openDialog () {
    location.hash = "#openModal"
    event.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: angular's default behavior is to go to visit the link and since`#openModal` is not registered in angular's router, the angular app just restarts.

Comment: Right, would adding `location.hash = "#openModal"` to the openDialog function work?

Comment: adding `location.hash = "#openModal"` to `openDialog` function makes the modal popup but it's just a flash, the angular app restarts immediately.

Comment: aha, it works when I changed `openDialog` like `    openDialog(){
        location.hash = "#openModal"
        event.preventDefault();
    }`